# Favorites features are unresponsive

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

My Favorites buttons in IE8 has become unresponsive. Nothing hapens if I click *Add to favorites*, *Organize favorites*, *Add to Favorites field* (I don't have the english version of IE so the names might differ a bit)

What might have caused this is that I accidentally cut and pasted my favorites folder to another location. That's the folder at `C:\Documents and Settings\<Current User>\Favorites`.
When I placed it back where it was before these problems in IE started.

I have tried to restore these Registry Keys ([as described here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/31564.aspx)), they where missing but it didn't fix aything:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current
>   Version\Explorer\Shell folders
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current
>   Version\Explorer\User Shell folders
>   HKEY_USERS.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current
>   Version\Explorer\Shell folders
>   HKEY_USERS.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current
>   Version\Explorer\User Shell folders

I have reinstalled IE8 but the problem is still there.

I have also tried the [FIX IE utility](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-internet-explorer-with-fix-ie-utility)

Any other ideas that could try?

Comment: System restore may help!

Comment: Does a browser reset help?

Comment: I tried system restore 4 times but all of the restorations failed. I tried a browser reset but that didn't help either. Thanks for the comments but I've given up on this for now.